# utf8 to char encoding in pure C code example

Tags: c, utf-8, char, codepages

I have problem in working with strings in pure C lang (c89 standard). I receive some text from web service using sockets in utf8 format. Everything is ok with latin character. But I also have some cyrillic. And it is shown something like `Ð’ Ð¿ÐµÑ€ÐµÐ´Ð°Ð½Ð½Ð¾Ð¼`. How to convert `utf8` text with cyrillic to `char *` in pure C?

Comment: Saying "to char*" is the same as saying "to memory" - i.e. it does not make sense until you specify the target encoding (for example, КОИ-8).

Comment: what do you do with the text you receive? put it to a file? process it? display it on terminal?

Comment: If I debug and use watch list it shows Ð’ Ð¿ÐµÑ€ÐµÐ´Ð°Ð½Ð½Ð¾Ð¼. So if I use this text later to display it it will be wrong...

Comment: first of all - you should find out, what encoding you want in result.

Comment: you can dump everything in a file and open it in a text editor like notepad++, i think it is not showing correctly might be because windows supports utf-16 not utf-8

Answer (score 2):

You can't convert UTF-8 to `char *`, as `char *` doesn't have a prescribed format and one of the most common formats for `char *` is actually UTF-8. If you encounter any other encoding, you can use the good old standard *iconv*.